# how to change label properties in custom table row Titanium

Tags: titanium, tableview, titanium-mobile

i have a table view which contain a label in each row so what i want to do is changing the label backgroundColor and color on user click
but what i get is just changing the color and the background color is changed just on user click and then go back to default color

here is my listener :

```
 s_f_table1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       e.source.setBackgroundColor("red");
       e.source.color = "black";
       console.log(e.source.id);

});
```

Comment: you have to detect first it as label and then change the proerty

Comment: right.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
           e.source.setBackgroundColor("red");
           e.source.color = "black";
           console.log(e.source.id);

i have added it with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom layout try this:

```
tableView.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var label = e.row.children[0]; // Label doesn't has to be the first child, depend on your layout.

   label.color = "black";
   label.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

however if you have the default row style then you can setup properties as `selectedBackgroundColor`, `selectedColor` or `selectionStyle`. See the documentation http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow

or you can do following:

```
tableView.addEventListener("click", function(e) {    
   e.row.color = "black";
   e.row.backgroundColor = "red"; // Whole row
});
```

**Edit:** If you want to change a background color don't forget to disable selectionStyle of the row using: `selectionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE`

Comment: thanks man for help but when i work with the row it work but when i try to access the label inside the row which is the only one children of the row the font color changed but the background color just changed during the click

Comment: now it's work thanks man ,could you update your answer and add this comment